# dfu-programmer claims completion, but no change on chip

Tags: c, keyboard, atmega

### Summary

I'm trying to flash new firmware to an AMJ40 mechanical keyboard. I can flash the hex 'successfully' but the keyboard responds by reverting to its default behaviour.

### More detail

The base repo for this is [AMJ40](https://github.com/AMJKeyboard/AMJ40) and my version of it is [here](https://github.com/notionparallax/AMJ40).

I can `make` the new .hex file, and all seems to be in order, but then when I use the keyboard it just has its default behaviour.

I would just assume that something's not working in my code, but when I push the reset button the keyboard stops working, and after the make process sends a reset command it works again—just with the old layout.

Here's the output from `make dfu`

```
ben@um:~/projects/git/AMJ40/src$ make dfu
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 flash AMJ40_lufa.hex
Validating...
17124 bytes used (59.72%)
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 reset
```

I have tried to hold down various key combinations as [suggested here](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=41989.msg2126106#msg2126106).

I have also tried manually [emptying the chip](http://www.technoburst.net/2013/04/atmel-dfu-programmer-tutorial-for-linux.html). Here [are the contents of the memory after clearing it](https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/ef6057cb5c043f9c8c599a417cdc1ebe).

If I do a manual recreation of the `make dfu` command I get the same behaviour, i.e.:

```
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 flash layout.hex
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 start
```

The keymap I'm currently trying to flash looks like this:

```
KEYMAP(
    D,   O,   H,   E,   R,   T,   Y,   U,   I,   P,  A,  A,\
    D,   O,   H,   E,   R,   T,   Y,   J,   K,   L,  A,\
    D,   O,   H,   E,   R,   T,   Y,   M,   A,   A,  A,\
    A,   A,   A,        A,        A,        A,   A,  A),

 KEYMAP(
     F,   R,   U,   S,   T,   R,   A,   T,   E,   P,  A,  A,\
     D,   O,   H,   E,   R,   T,   Y,   J,   K,   L,  A,\
     D,   O,   H,   E,   R,   T,   Y,   M,   A,   A,  A,\
     A,   A,   A,        A,        A,        B,   B,  B),
```

This ludicrous keymap is to make it very clear that it's working or not. I'd expect the second key on the top row to print an O after flashing, but it always prints a Q (as a regular QWERTY keyboard would).

### Suspicions

I've looked, but there might be a file referenced *somewhere* in the build process that overwrites my intent.

There may also be some mysterious corner of the chip that keep restoring itself to its former settings, but I can't see how that would happen.

#### Disclaimer

This question isn't necessarily a programming question, but there were several other dfu-programmer that haven't been closed as off topic, so they have emboldened me.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question to [Geekhack](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=87160.0) and their user, [odd](https://geekhack.org/index.php?action=profile;u=53215) suggested:

> The keymap is in EEPROM so it persists over reboots. ... Also the QMK firmware has a erase EEPROM hex you can use to wipe it.

That's the answer. The command `dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase` doesn't wipe the eeprom. To do that you need to overwrite it with something else. In this case, the something else is a .hex file from the [QMK quantum tools](https://github.com/jackhumbert/qmk_firmware/tree/master/quantum/tools).

There is a slight tweak in that the documentation says it should be:

```
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 flash-eeprom eeprom_reset.hex
```

But in my version of dfu-programmer it needed to be

```
dfu-programmer atmega32u4 flash --eeprom eeprom_reset.hex
```

I added this into my `make` process. I copied the hex file mentioned above into my repo, and then changed `tmk_core_custom/rules.mk` to have the following in the dfu section

```
dfu: $(TARGET).hex
...
    dfu-programmer $(MCU) erase
    dfu-programmer $(MCU) flash-eeprom tools/eeprom_reset.hex # <-add this line
    dfu-programmer $(MCU) erase
    dfu-programmer $(MCU) flash $(TARGET).hex
    dfu-programmer $(MCU) reset
```

This means that I can now do a `make dfu` all in one step.

#### Future things

1. I've put that line into the `tmk_core_custom` submodule. Ideally, I'd find a way for it to live in *my* repo.
2. Given that these chips have a limited number of writes, it might be nice to check first if it needs to have the eeprom flashed.

I'm totally up for suggestions to make this answer better!